# How to repeat birthday date every year using Fullcalendar.io?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fullcalendar

I am working on a system using Fullcalendar.io plug-in.

I have a form that a user has to enter their birthday date and store in database MySQL. The form works and the date successfully stored in database using "date" type. Then how to make the birthday date repeat every year on the fullcalendar?

`calendarload.php`

```
foreach($result as $res){$date=date('d/F/Y', strtotime($res['birthday']));
$data[] = array(
    'title'   => $res["name"], 
    'start'   => $res['birthday'],
    'bday'   => $date
); }
```

`index.php`

```
eventRender: function(event, element) { 
   element.append("<b>" + event.bday + "<b>");
},
```

I prefer using MySQLi than PDO.

Comment: fullCalendar doesn't currently support recurring events directly. So either you'd have to create a series of separate events , yearly on that date for as many years as you realistically expect a user might scroll backwards and forwards within the calendar.

Comment: Or, you could [search for existing solutions](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=active&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&ei=YTDgW9HUCKmNgAavw6K4CA&q=fullcalendar+recurring+events+yearly&oq=fullcalendar+recurring+events+yearly&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i13k1.7939.8643.0.8760.7.7.0.0.0.0.94.577.7.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.7.573...0j0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1.0.JxyhuYdAc2k) which allow you to specify recurrence rules for an event. Did you not search for anything before posting?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it!

I just separate the date into $day, $month and $year.

This is my code and it works for my case.

```
foreach($result as $res){
$date1=date('d-F-Y', strtotime($res['birthday']));
$date=strtotime($res['birthday']);
$time  = $date;
$day   = date('d',$time);
$month = date('m',$time);
$year  = date('Y',$time);
$curryear = date('Y');

$data[] = array(
    'title'   => $res["name"], 
    'start'   => $curryear . "-" . $month . "-" . $day,
    'bday'   => $date1
);}
```

so whenever the computer changes Year.. the birthday date will be the same because I change to $curryear .